# 172.16.33.197, 127.0.0.1 IP addresses in visitor logs

Tags: php, apache, ip-spoofing

I have a website running Apache and PHP. I see that there are visitors with IP addresses 172.16.33.197 and 127.0.0.1. These addresses do not belong to our network. I get the visitor IP addresses with following code snippet.

```
function GetUserIP() {

    if (isset($_SERVER)) {

        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
            return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
            return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

        return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        return getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        return getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');

    return getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
}
```

Why can I see that this IP address visiting my website?
Does this indicate a security breach or a problem with my code?

Comment: Just a note, that `127.0.0.1` is the address for the localhost. It is also non-routable - so it was either sourced from your server, or it was faked there somehow.

Comment: Try sending this packet to your server: `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nX-FORWARDED-FOR: cookies!\r\n\r\n` Congrats, you just forged your own IP to 'cookies'!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. If the user alters the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header, or any of the  user-supplied headers you're checking with that code, they can forge the source IP. Ignore those headers and just use the REMOTE_ADDR value.

Comment: Just because they are user supplies does not mean they are supplied by *your* user.  Many proxies happily provide that header. The HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header can be safely used for a blacklist in conjunction with the REMOTE_ADDR.

Comment: Both ip is listed for the same tcp request. How are tcp packets are returned to fake originating ip? Morever 172.16.33.197 is not publicly routable.

Comment: @nsumer - That means it was forged.  Your code is flawed.